# What's the best way to make a number picker with arrows?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I want to make a number picker that looks like this to input any number from 0 to 99.

[image]

My code so far looks like this (where leftDigit and rightDigit are the Text components in Unity that change with every arrow key hit). I linked this function to all four arrow buttons and gave them 10, -10, 1, -1 as parameters respectively to update the inputNumber in my script.

```
public void UpdateUINumber(int value)
{
    if (inputNumber + value >= 0)
    {
        inputNumber += value;
        if (Mathf.Abs(value) == 1 && (inputNumber / 10) != int.Parse(leftDigit.text))
            inputNumber -= value * 10;
        leftDigit.text = ((inputNumber / 10) % 10).ToString();
        rightDigit.text = (inputNumber % 10).ToString();
    }
}
```

However I have a feeling my code could be even more compact and elegant. I really want to keep the single UpdateUINumber function linked to all 4 buttons.
Do you have any idea about how I could upgrade this function with maybe arithmetics involved? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
[SerializeField] private Text[] _numbers;

public int Value { get; private set; }

public void ValueModifire (int value) {
    Value += value;
    Value = Mathf.Max(0, Value);
    ViewNumber(Value);
}

private void ViewNumber (int number) {
    string StrNumber = number.ToString();
    int Difference = _numbers.Length-StrNumber.Length;
    // add symbols 1 -> 01
    // depends on count of text objects 
    if (Difference > 0)
        StrNumber.PadLeft(Difference, '0');
    // for each text, a string character is set by the index 
    // no matter how many there are 2 or 20 
    for (int i = 0; i < _numbers.Length; i++)
        _numbers.text = StrNumber[i];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because if my current number is 19 and I add 1 to the ones digit, I want to output 10 and not 20. Similarly, 10 - 1 = 19 in the system I'm looking for.

Comment: in OnClick Button Event you can set argument for function `1`/`10`/`-1`/`-10`. One Component for all your system, not for each number.

Comment: You mean editing the onClick event in the code? I don't plan on having more than 2 digits, that's not the issue, what I'm really looking for is to turn lines 5,6,7 into a single "inputNumber = ..." line

Comment: OnClick on inspector interface.

Comment: oh okay well that's exactly what I pass to the UpdateUINumber function already